# For NoUiSlider, how do I set the width of a handle/thumb?

Tags: javascript, css, nouislider

I have attempted to set the width of a NoUiSlider
via the css:

```
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle {
    width:8px;
    height:25px;
    left: 0px;
    top: -8px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: #000;
    cursor: default;
    box-shadow: none; /*inset 0 0 1px #FFF, inset 0 1px 7px #EBEBEB, 0 3px 6px -3px #BBB;*/ }

.noUi-handle {
     left:0px; }

.noUi-active {
    box-shadow: none /*inset 0 0 1px #FFF, inset 0 1px 7px #DDD, 0 3px 6px -3px #BBB;*/ }

.noUi-handle:before, .noUi-handle:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 14px;
    width: 0px;
    background: #000000;
    left: 14px;
    top: 6px; }

.noUi-handle:after {
    left: 0px; }
```

Thought this does give me the narrow handle that I want, the handle no longer covers the 
transition in the track between white and green,
but rather that transition is exposed, unlike 
when you don't change the handle width.

Answer (score 3):

One of the complications of using nouislider is getting a complete answer.
I've made one below incorporating lg102's response, and added a few things
to make it more obvious. I needed to use !important in the CSS to make
some properties take effect.

Something like this example would make a good addition to 
nouislider's website doc, which is already way better
than the average doc for a JS library.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="nouislider.js"></script> 
   <link href="nouislider.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script>
     function init(){
        noUiSlider.create(slider_id, {
                start: [25, 75],
                connect: [false, true, false],
                range: {
                    'min': 0, 
                    'max': 100
                }
            })
      }
   </script>
   <style>
     .noUi-handle {
        width: 10px !important;
        right: -5px !important; /*  must be (width / 2) * -1 */
        background: #AA00AA;
     }
   </style>
</head>
<body onload="init()" >
<h3>slide test1</h3>
<div id="slider_id" style="width:300px;height:20px;"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `left` value for `.noUi-handle` to `0`. The default CSS for LTR sliders looks like this:

```
.noUi-handle {
    width: 34px;
    height: 28px;
    left: auto;
    right: -17px; /* The 17 here is half of the 34 width. The - pulls it in the other direction */
    top: -6px;
}
```

Since you are changing the width to `8`, you should set the `right` (or `left`, depending on the page orientation) to `-4` (8/2).

The minimum changes to make are adding:

```
width: 10px;
right: -5px;
```

You can try this out in the documentation:

[image: demonstration of change slider handle width using CSS]

Comment: Lg102  First, -17 is not half of 34.  17 is. Second, .noUi-handle {
    width: 34px;
    height: 28px;
    left: -17px; /* The -17 here is half of the 34 width */
    top: -6px;
} does not appear in nouislider.css v. 13.1.1 but there are two different css bodies for the selector .noUi-handle in that file.  Third, changing left: to 4px or -4px (couldn't figure out which I should use based on your comment, I'm using left to right) did not appear to affect my problem.  I am using html of: <div id='mi_marks_slider_id' style='display:inline-block; width:270px;height:10px;'></div>