# nouislider handle passes its bar length

Tags: javascript, css, responsive, nouislider

I'm using [nouislider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) in my project, and it works fine. However, it seems when you change the `handle` width the slider doesn't recalculate the step length.

Live example:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider')

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
  start: [0],
  range: {
    min: 0,
    max: 4
  },
  step: 1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.0.2/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.0.2/nouislider.min.css">

<style>
  /* custom styles */
  
  .noUi-tooltip {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: none;
    color: inherit;
  }
  
  .noUi-target {
    height: 2px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: unset;
    background: #e6e6e6;
  }
  
  .noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  
  .noUi-handle {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: unset;
    border: 0;
    right: -100px;
  }
  
  .noUi-handle:after,
  .noUi-handle:before {
    content: unset;
  }
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Also the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmo2L5ke/).

As you can see, the `handle` overflows the "bar lenght".

From the docs is says:

> Responsive design friendly

Is there a way for it to automatically recalculate the `handle` position? Or I must use media queries or add extra JS logic for it to work?

Thanks

Similar issue - [For NoUiSlider, how do I set the width of a handle/thumb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130554/for-nouislider-how-do-i-set-the-width-of-a-handle-thumb)

---

Update:

[From the docs:](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-styling)

> `.noUi-origin` - The elements connected to the base, defining the handle locations.

That element gets a dynamic value for the `transform: translate(-1000%, 0px)`, depending on the `handle` position. Maybe some additional JS should be added on that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handle can be any width, and isn't constrained by the slider width. You can achieve what you want by setting a `padding` on `.noUi-target`. That's mentioned in the documentation [here](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-styling).

```
.noUi-target {
    padding: 0 17px;
}
.noUi-connects {
    margin: 0 -17px;
    width: calc(100% + 34px);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to update the offset (`right`) for the handle when changing its width. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7p590uyd/

Comment: Yes, that's it! Works like a charm now. Thanks for the help! Cheers :)